# Question on my Bradford Pear Tree

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees

We have 2 Bradford Pear trees out front. This spring the one on the right was full of blooms, the left one was very scarce of blooms, the right tree is full of leaves, the left one is almost bare. We are very worried about our tree. Are there any suggestions you can give us to save our tree, and hopefully not have the one on the right catch whatever is wrong with the left.

Comment: You might want to move this to Gardening.SE, they might be able to provide better answers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology, and should instead be asked on [gardening.se].

Comment: Pictures, please? You can [edit] your post any time. Welcome to Gardening SE!